# Make a bootstrap Gallery Dynamic with Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use the bootstrap 4 gallery however I am a bit lost I have my carsoul showing just with dummy data at present.

As you will notice the bootstrap carousel identifies each image with a number I need to know how to handle this.

This is the orginal code pen I found

https://codeply.com/go/tBbcVXe1xZ

I tried to setup a dotnetfiddle but was unsure how the models works on the online compiler

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cc5ahV

I have to account for this on the mini pictures

```
id="carousel-selector-1" data-slide-to="1"
```

And this for the large pictures

Where the numbers in both should increase per photo

```
<div class="container">  
    <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2" id="slider">
     <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide shadow" styl>
        <!-- main slider carousel items -->
        @foreach (var item in FileAttachments)
         {
               <div class="carousel-inner">
               <div class="active carousel-item" data-slide-number="0">
               <img src="https://photo-assets.superyachttimes.com/photo/121447/image/large-7b0d6a0b3217dd17aa8cc9e9eef912f8.jpg" class="img-fluid">
               </div> 
        }//this should print out same div set for every image attached to the record
                                          
    </div>
          <!-- main slider carousel nav controls -->
          <ul class="carousel-indicators list-inline mx-auto border px-2">
          @foreach (var item in FileAttachments)
          {
            <li class="list-inline-item active">
             <a id="carousel-selector-0" class="selected" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel">
             <img src="https://photo-assets.superyachttimes.com/photo/121447/image/large-7b0d6a0b3217dd17aa8cc9e9eef912f8.jpg" style="width: 86px; height:86px" class="img-fluid">
             </a>
            </li>
            }
             <li class="list-inline-item">
               <a id="carousel-selector-1" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel">
               <img src="https://photo-assets.superyachttimes.com/photo/121447/image/large-7b0d6a0b3217dd17aa8cc9e9eef912f8.jpg" style="width: 86px; height:86px" class="img-fluid">
               </a>
             </li>
            </ul>
           </div>
```

The model would be

```
 public class FileAttachments
 {
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string UrlOrPath
    {
        get;
        set
    }
  }
```

**Edit 2**

```
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide shadow" styl>
                                            <!-- main slider carousel items -->
                                            <div class="carousel-inner">

                                                    <div class="active carousel-item active" data-slide-number="1">
                                                        <img src="/Uploads/7bbc8503-a686-40d3-b70c-d6f0e0423e9b_DILBAR4.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="active carousel-item " data-slide-number="2">
                                                        <img src="/Uploads/cc4263a9-cdfe-48a2-82d4-b976d76b9a3c_DILBAR3.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                                    </div>

                                                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                                </a>
                                                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                                </a>

                                            </div>
                                            <!-- main slider carousel nav controls -->


                                            <ul class="carousel-indicators list-inline mx-auto border px-2">

                                                    <li class="list-inline-item active">
                                                        <a id="carousel-selector-1" class="selected" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel">
                                                            <img src="/Uploads/7bbc8503-a686-40d3-b70c-d6f0e0423e9b_DILBAR4.jpg" style="width: 86px; height: 86px" class="img-fluid">
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="list-inline-item active">
                                                        <a id="carousel-selector-2" class="selected" data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel">
                                                            <img src="/Uploads/cc4263a9-cdfe-48a2-82d4-b976d76b9a3c_DILBAR3.jpg" style="width: 86px; height: 86px" class="img-fluid">
                                                        </a>
                                                    </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
```

I have tried the following razor but it doesnt produce what i need from the code pen

The above html is produced by the below razor but its not working the next and previous.

```
                                        @{int i = 0;}
                                        @foreach (var item in Model.PhotosAttachments) {
                                            i++;
                                            var active = i == 1 ? "active" : "";

                                            <div class="active carousel-item @active" data-slide-number="@i">
                                                <img src="~/Uploads/@item.File" class="img-fluid">
                                            </div>
                                        }

                                        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                        </a>

                                    </div>
                                    <!-- main slider carousel nav controls -->


                                    <ul class="carousel-indicators list-inline mx-auto border px-2">

                                        @{int j = 0;}
                                        @foreach (var item in Model.PhotosAttachments) {
                                            j++;
                                            <li class="list-inline-item active">
                                                <a id="carousel-selector-@j" class="selected" data-slide-to="@j" data-target="#myCarousel">
                                                    <img src="~/Uploads/@item.File" style="width: 86px; height: 86px" class="img-fluid">
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        }
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else this is what works I just had to do a counter in relation to the loop.

```
 <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2" id="slider">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide shadow">
        <!-- main slider carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">

            @{int i = 0;}

            @foreach (var item in Model.PhotosAttachments) {
                var active = i == 0 ? "active" : "";

                <div class="@active carousel-item" data-slide-number="@i">
                    <img src="~/Uploads/@item.File" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
                i++;

            }

            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>

        </div>
        <!-- main slider carousel nav controls -->


        <ul class="carousel-indicators list-inline mx-auto border px-2">

            @{int j = 0;}
            @foreach (var item in Model.PhotosAttachments) {
                var active = i == 0 ? "active" : "";
                var isSelected = i == 0 ? "selected" : "";

                <li class="list-inline-item @active">
                    <a id="carousel-selector-@j" class="@isSelected" data-slide-to="@j" data-target="#myCarousel">
                        <img src="~/Uploads/@item.File" style="width: 86px; height: 86px" class="img-fluid">
                    </a>
                </li>
                j++;

            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```